# SWF won't load a XML file while being called from a webpage on Apache

Tags: xml, flash, apache

I have a swf that I put on my page like this

```
<object width='670' height='580'> 
    <embed src='../flash/galeria.swf' width='670' height='580' /> 
</object>
```

There is a  XML that it reads and creates some stuff. The problem is that when I run it on my computer it works fine, but when it runs through the page, it won't load the xml. The paths are correct, I'm sure of this, because I run it outside of the server (Apache) and it works.

PS: The xml only loads outside of the server if I publish the SWF with the option "Local playblack securty" set with " acess local files only". I tried to change it to "acess network only" and it won't work outside of the server, and also not while being called from the page on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. While I launched the SWF from the filesystem, on windows, the relative path was relative to the place where I was running the SWF. When I ran it embeded on my webpage, and the page and the SWF where in different directories , but all files that the SWF needed were the same as before, it didn't work. I had to move the files the SWF called to the same directory of the webpage that calls the SWF - only this way it worked. Thanks.